# Prove using Arzelà-Ascoli theorem that the image of this function is compact.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $K:[0,1]\times[0,1]\to\mathbb{R}$ be continuous and define the operator $L:C([0,1])\to C([0,1])$ by

$$\displaystyle Lf(x) = \int_0^1 K(x,y)f(y) dy.$$

Then the closure $\overline{L(B_1(0))}$ of the image of the unit ball under $L$ is compact in $C([0,1])$.

So I want to use  Arzelà-Ascoli theorem, then I only need to prove that $\overline{L(B_1(0))}$ is closed in $C([0,1])$,equicontinous and pointwise bounded.

Then, by definition of $L$ we get that $\overline{L(B_1(0))} \subset C([0,1])$, hence it is closed in $C([0,1])$ Am I rigth here?. The thing is that for equicontinuity I dont know how to apply the Mean Value Theorem, because I don't know if it is differentiable or if I can differentiate under the integral sign, and I tried to do this task by hand (this is, trying to apply the triangle inequality)but I got nothing and the same for the pointwise bound. Therefore my question is Can someone help me to prove this result please?

Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Pointwise boundedness should be easy: if $f \in B_1(0)$ then $|f| \le 1$ everywhere, and $|K| \le 1$ everywhere also.  Your sentence that starts "Then by definition of $L$" is sort of rambling: the closure of a set is by definition closed, done.

Comment: How do you know that the uniform norm of $K$ is one ?

Comment: Oops, I misread the first sentence.  But continuous functions are bounded, so there is a constant $M$ such that $|K| \le M$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Since $K$ is continuous on $[0,1] \times [0,1]$ and that set is compact, $K$ is uniformly continuous. In particular, given $\epsilon > 0$ there exists $\delta > 0$ so that if $|x_1-x_2| < \delta$, then $|K(x_1,y) - K(x_2,y)| < \epsilon$ for any $y \in [0,1]$. (Note: I didn't use the full strength of uniform continuity here).

If $f \in B_1(0)$ then $|x_1 - x_2| < \delta$ implies $$|Lf(x_1) - Lf(x_2)| \le \int_0^1 |K(x_1,y) - K(x_2,y)| |f(y)| \, dy < \epsilon \int_0^1 |f(y)| \, dy = \epsilon$$
since $\sup_{x \in [0,1]} |f(x)| \le 1.$

Thus the family $LB_1(0)$ is equicontinuous, and rather easily seen to be uniformly bounded.

Comment: Thanks @Umberto and all what you've done is using the uniform norm right?

Comment: And How did you realize the second inequality?